# WebAutomation using C++

Tags: c++, web, url, visual-c++, webautomation

I have to open an Url which is this -> "https://82.165.114.16:24850/swagger-ui/". Then after opening it. I have to select an Option called Authorize in it and enter my credentials to log in to it.

I have to do all these things in a single c++ program code.

I know there are better options available with other programming languages. So, anyone here suggests to me the possible ways to built c++ dll.

But here I would like to create a c++ dll which will be used in java in later times.

Thanks in advance. Waiting for exciting replies.

Yours Sincerely,
Mustaq Ahmed Althaf Hussain

Comment: Using `system` you will have a very hard time doing it. You first have to find the browser window, then you have to get access to its process, and then find the link inside the memory of that process, and force the process to "click" it. Perhaps use [WinInet functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/wininet-functions) or similar framework instead?

Comment: Yes, Now check my question I have changed the code to open the URL. Could also please explain to me in detail about the browser window and getting access to its process and link inside the memory of that process. What did you mean exactly in your comment?